# Почему форма невалидна?

Tags: django

При регистрации нового пользователя в админке появляется надпись "Ошибка регистрации".
Как это можно исправить?

```
forms.py 

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from .models import Profile
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Вы успешно зарегестрировались!')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка')
            print('Выдает ошибку')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
    print('Выдает ошибку')
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wishlist = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: `form.save()` надо так

Answer (score 0):

`form.save()` - вы должны вызвать функцию save у формы, а не указать её.